# Resultados en formato JSON de una consulta MySQL - Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, json

Tengo una duda sobre esto. ¿Es posible convertir una consulta MySQL a formato JSON sin hacer uso de funciones PHP ni estar iterando para recién convertirlo a JSON?

Me explico, tengo el siguiente JSON que fue sacado de una consulta, representa que pelicula le gusta ver a cada uno:

- Caso 01

```
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "nombre": "Mario",
    "categoria": "Accion",
    "pelicula": "Mision de Rescate"
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "nombre": "Mario",
    "categoria": "Accion",
    "pelicula": "Escuadron 6"
  },
  {
    "id": "3",
    "nombre": "Camila",
    "categoria": "Terror",
    "pelicula": "Eli"
  }
]
```

Como podemos ver a `Mario` le gusta las peliculas de `Mision de Rescate` y `Escuadron 6` de categoria `Accion`, esto a convertirlo a un formato JSON (**no se como se llama este proceso**) seria asi:

- Caso 02

```
{
  "Mario": {
    "Accion": {
      "peliculas": [
        "Mision de Rescate",
        "Escuadron 6"
      ]
    }
  },
  "Camila": {
    "Terror": {
      "peliculas": [
        "Eli"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Para hacer este proceso, existen varias formas en PHP, desde usar funciones hasta hacer modelos de agrupación e ir llenando el formato que queramos.

Actualmente estoy usando Laravel, nose si en este framework tenga una opcion para transformar mis consultas que hago en el formato que quiero como es en el `Caso 02`, o simplemente haya una forma de hacer esto directamente desde la BD

Nuevamente pregunto si no me entendieron, lo que quiero hacer es convertir del `Caso 01` al `Caso 02` sin estar iterando el JSON para recien tener lo que quiero (`Caso 02`), esto lo digo porque en una consulta siempre va haber datos que se repiten como el de `categoria` o `nombre`

En el caso de que no fuera posible, me gustaría saber formas simples para hacer eso, en mi caso, encontre una forma muy simple que seria el uso de la funcion `array_reduce`

- Usando `array_reduce`

```
$resultado =  array_reduce($personas, function($accumulator, $item){
    $index = $item['nombre'];

    if (!isset($accumulator[$index])) {
        $accumulator[$index] = [ $item['categoria'] => [] ];
    }
    $accumulator[$index][$item['categoria']]['peliculas'][] = $item['pelicula'];

    return $accumulator;
}, []);
```

Todo lo que dije anteriormente se puede hacer simplemente usando una BD no relacional pero ahora estoy usando una BD relacional

Esto en Laravel `Query Builder` y `Eloquent`

Comment: Tienes Modelos: Pelicula, Usuario, Categoria en tu proyecto?

Comment: Este es un ejemplo pero si lo implementaría si tendría @L.Flor

Comment: Laravel te ofrece obtener resultados así debido a las relaciones Eloquent: https://pastebin.com/vpXVMdMb Y así facilmente poder acceder `$user->peliculas->categoria`, `$user->categorias->peliculas`, pero si no es lo que buscas entonces no servirá pero no estarías recorriendo con un `for` para agrupar los resultados manualmente.

Comment: En el caso de que fuera `Query Builder`, habría una forma? @L.Flor

Comment: En ese caso sería más complejo pero sí se podría, y tendrías que utilizar Collections.

Comment: Podrías explicarme o darme una referencia de donde comenzar?

Comment: ¿Qué relaciones existen entre las entidades?

Comment: Lo puse como ejemplo pero las relaciones seria de uno a muchos. Puedes colocar tu propio ejemplo, lo que me interesa es obtener los datos como el `Caso 02`

Answer (score 1):

Para obtener un formato parecido al que buscas existen dos formas por las que puedes empezar, una es con Eloquent y otra con Query Builder.

**1. [Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)**

Para obtener datos relacionados con Eloquent necesidas definir las relaciones en los modelos, por lo que asumiendo que tienes 3 modelos: Pelicula, Usuario, Categoria:

`Pelicula.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Pelicula extends Model
{
    public function categoria()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Categoria');
    }
}
```

`Categoria.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Categoria extends Model
{
    public function peliculas()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Pelicula');
    }
}
```

`Usuario.php` (Aquí la relación la haré así, pero necesitarías una tabla intermedia para alojar todas las películas que le gustan a un usuario)

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Usuario extends Model
{
    public function peliculas()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Pelicula');
    }
}
```

Posteior a esto, simplemente si quieres obtener todos los usuarios con las peliculas que les gustan harías algo así:

```
Usuario::with('peliculas')->get();
```

O si haces la relación Many to Many, podrás acceder más detalladamente:

```
Categoria::with('peliculas')->get(); // Peliculas dentro de su categoria
Categoria::with('usuarios')->get();  // Usuarios dentro de una categoria
```

En fin, es cuestión de que investigues más a fondo sobre las relaciones y cómo deseas obtener los resultados

**2. [Query Builder](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries)**

Si lo trabajas con esto, tendrás que construir tu propia query, luego utilizar métodos de Collections para armar tu deseado json.

Ejemplo:

```
$resultados = DB::table('usuarios AS u')
    ->select('u.nombre_usuario', 'cat.descripcion', 'p.descripcion')
    ->join('usuario_pelicula AS up','up.usuario_id', 'u.usuario_id')
    ->join('pelicula AS p', 'p.pelicula_id', 'up.pelicula_id')
    ->join('categoria AS cat', 'cat.categoria_id', 'p.categoria_id')
    ->get();
```

Con eso tendrías la data agrupada como en tu ejemplo 1, posteriormente a eso usas [Collections](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections), usando [mapToGroups](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-maptogroups):

```
$collection = collect($resultados);

$agrupado = $collection->mapToGroups(function ($item, $key) {
    return [$item['nombre'] => $item['pelicula']];
});
```

`$agrupado` retornaría algo así:

```
[
    'Mario' => ['Mision de Rescate', 'Escuadron 6'],
    'Camila' => ['Eli'],
]
```

De todas maneras, existen muchísimos más métodos en collections que pueden ayudarte a conseguir lo requerido. Puedes leerlos en la documentación.

Comment: Interesante, veo que en versiones antiguas de Laravel no hay esa función pero para ser "lo mismo" se utiliza `groupBy`. Esto mismo se haría se existirá varias relaciones? Por ejemplo dentro de las películas hay una calificación y dentro de las calificaciones están las personas que calificaron

Comment: Son todas relaciones, si haces algo así seria: `Pelicula::with('calificacion.usuarios')->get()`. Dentro de calificaciones deberías tener una relación con usuarios